# how to get latest date from two conditions?

Tags: mysql

I have drop down where the drop down is list of namaJabatan

### my table - infojawatan

1. ID - PK of the table
2. namaJabatan - where the condition appear ($search - its up to where the user select from Dropdown)
3. tarikhKemaskini - where i want to get the latest date of row

### my query

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM infojawatan WHERE namaJabatan = '$search' && tarikh Kemaskini IN (SELECT MAX(tarikhKemaskini) FROM infojawatan GROUP BY ID)";
                                $sql_rs = mysql_query($sql);
                                while($row_Sql = mysql_fetch_array($sql_rs)) {
                                    $tarikhKemaskini = $row_Sql['tarikhKemaskini'];
                                }
                                echo "Current Date :" .$tarikhKemaskini;
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to a [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attack. Always use bind parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few syntax errors in your SQL.

- SQL spells out `AND`, not `&&`.
- `tarikhKemaskini` is one word.

```
SELECT *
FROM infojawatan
WHERE namaJabatan = :namaJabatan AND
      tarikhKemaskini IN (
          SELECT MAX(tarikhKemaskini)
          FROM infojawatan
          GROUP BY ID
      )
```

Note carefully that I used `:namaJabatan` there instead of hard coding `$search`. Hard coding variables into SQL leaves you open to a [SQL Injection Attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) where a malicious attacker can craft a search query that lets them get more information than they're allowed to, or even run arbitrary SQL queries.

Instead, use parameters, the `:namaJabatan` there, and pass your variables in when you execute the query.

Unfortunately the `mysql_query` interface doesn't support this. Fortunately [it was deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) and there are now better interfaces. [Here's a breakdown](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php). I'd recommend using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) as it is a generic interface applicable to any SQL database. Then you can use the more secure and efficient [prepared statements with bind parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("
    SELECT *
    FROM infojawatan
    WHERE namaJabatan = :namaJabatan AND
          tarikhKemaskini IN (
              SELECT MAX(tarikhKemaskini)
              FROM infojawatan
              GROUP BY ID
          )
")
$stmt->execute(array( ':namaJabatan' => $search));
while( $row = $stmt->fetch() ) {
    echo $row['tarikhKemaskini'];
}
```